# Converting system of s-domain equations to block diagram (control system designing)

Tags: control-system, block-diagram

Hi I am new to control system and block diagrams.

I have the following question:

[image]

I just want to ask if my interpretation of how the block diagram should be designed is correct? (see below)

[image]

Comment: Yes - the block diagram looks good, but you should note that the shown functions are NOT differential equations but transfer functions in the s-domain. And, please, you should make use of brackets in te denominator. More than that, the last block which must be a summing block looks like a multiplier

Comment: @LvW: That's the answer, you should post it as such.  As to the summation junction -- there's a lot of block diagram dialects out there.  In the typical radio block diagram usage, a circle divided by an "X" is, indeed, a multiplier (or a frequency summation) -- but in typical older control systems block diagrams that exact thing is used to denote a summing junction.

Comment: Thank you to both of you, I think I get it :-)